# Can secure HTTP headers like be ignored for js and static HTML pages?

Tags: appsec, secure-coding

I am performing a security scan on a website and the ZAP tool reports some secure headers are missing for js and static HTML pages. Is it ok to ignore the alerts ?

Comment: What are secure headers? Maybe you can give some examples

Comment: perhaps are you referring to [these security headers](https://www.dionach.com/blog/an-overview-of-http-security-headers)?

Answer (score 1):

What I think it means, is that you need to protect your site against XSS attacks enforcing your js/css origins.

**1. Content-Security-Policy: allows you to restrict the origin**

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 
https://apis.google.com
```

**2. X-Frame-Options : Stop Clickjacking**

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

**3. X-Content-Type-Options: Enforce content-type**

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/plain
```

**4. Strict-Transport-Security: Enforce HTTPS**

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

**5. X-Requested-With: prevent CSRF attacks**

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Be aware that some of these headers are not all browser-compatible. Read the source link below and use those you feel fits your project.

Source:
https://www.ibuildings.nl/blog/2013/03/4-http-security-headers-you-should-always-be-using

Comment: Good tips, I think that it is important to include "HttpOnly" and "Secure" attributes. The first avoid that a cookie can be obtained through Javascript code, it's a good security measure against XSS attacks; the second enforce a cookie to be sent trough a secure channel (HTTPS), it's a good secuirty measure against Man in the middle attacks.